# How does Xcode know which profile the application belongs to?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have been wondering about how does xcode link the provisioning profile to a particular application.

For example, I install profile named 'myprofile' in the organizer and go to the project name 'newapp' and say build and go.
The application 'newapp' is installed fine on the iphone but how do i know if there is a link between 'newapp' and 'myprofile'.

What happens if i change my app name and again say build and go?

This is what i do:
 1. Login to my account.
 2. Create a new app id: 'first'
 3. Use existing device: 'myiphone'
 4. enter the profile name: 'myprofile', download it
 5. install it inside organizer. (Till this point no application is assigned to the profile)
 6. Now go to my project: 'newapp' just say build and go and app runs on the device.

I never selected a profile and said assign the app to this profile so...
How can i say that 'myprofile' is tied to 'newapp'?

Thanks

Comment: Apple's software is smarter than you think.

Comment: agreed... but there should be some indication of whats going on...

Answer (score 1):

Its your app bundle identifier from the project-info.plist file that is mapped to a profile. You can ofcourse have wildcard characters and use a profile to build multiple apps.

Comment: @ Hetal: i dont wish to have multiple apps with a profile... i want to find out how does xcode assign an app to a profile when i say build and go...

Comment: It matches the bundle identifier of your app to that associated with a profile. In most cases, you have to manually select the profile you want to sign your app with through project settings.

Comment: My bundle identifier is default i.e. com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}... can i change this?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set which profile an app will use in the build settings (under "Code Signing Identity"). The default for this is automatic which will match based on your app identifier (com.example.appname).

Comment: @David: Yes i am aware of that... but how does the app identifier correspond to an application name... my app name was 'newapp' and app id was 'trial'... what if i install two new profiles, which one will the xcode autoselect?

Comment: If they both have the same app id it's undefined.

Comment: @David: If they are different?

Comment: It will select the one that matches your app id in Info.plist.

Comment: @David: i cant see any field called app id in indo.plist... there is a bundle identifier... are they the same?

Comment: Yes bundle identifier and app id are the same thing.